# Is it possible to specify the order of the tests in Visual Studio c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I have several tests in the same namespace. I did not use naming convention like Test1, Test2, ... etc for each of my unit tests. So, now when I run all tests, they don't run in the order I want them to. Is there a way to order tests?

My tests do not fail if I don't execute them in a particular order. However, I was just wanted to execute them in the order they are in my test case spreadsheet.

Comment: You're going to get lots of comments saying it shouldn't matter if they're proper unit tests!

Comment: It shouldn't matter if they're proper...

Comment: I agree with the proper unit test notion, however for debugging a large number of tests, it might be useful to be able to record which order the tests ran in.  This would allow the tests to be debugged so that they are proper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is Yes.  Although I agree with the principles of isolation there are scenarios where you need to test a sequence of events.  In VS 2010 you can create a new 'Ordered Test' to bundle and test a set of tests sequentially.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive A code example or link to what an "Ordered Test" actually is would be fabulous!

Comment: @iGanja - Here is a sample.  I zipped it and put it up on my Blob Store - http://j.mp/so-tests-sample

Answer (score 9):

Your tests should not be order-dependent; that breaks the concept of test noninterdependence.  The lack of ability to order the tests in Visual Studio is a reflection of this concept.

Comment: Then define how there's a test type called Ordered Test, where you select which unit tests to run, and in which order.

Answer (score 5):

Oh man, you are violating one of the major Unit Testing rules - "Isolation".

Test should never have any dependecy order. Do not wait for the answer, go and refactor you tests to be really independt each of other. Believe me, it is better to do now :)

Comment: Thanks! My tests are not dependent, but I just wanted them to execute in the order they are in my test case spreadsheet.

Comment: I know this question is kind of old but I've the same problem. I've two independent tests which communicate with a database I am not in control of. For a proper test run I need the activation test to run before the deactivate test. Is there a way for that? Does that also violate the "major" unit testing rules of isolation?

Since I wanted to use unit tests to verify that my communication with the database server is working correct I didn't want to host my own test database just for my unit tests.

Comment: the test you are talking about is integration tests. there are basically another rules for that. I think in your case you need something like Setup/TearDown for tests. Setup would do activation. it is very hard to implement intergration test in full isolation, since too many dependencies it has.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has a built-in template for ordered tests (assuming you're using the MSTest framework). If you open the context-menu in a test-project, it is available under the "New Test" menu or directly as "Ordered Test". Never used that before, but I'm assuming that your tests get still executed in an undefined order if you are running all your tests in the solution.